# loop through a list of series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to loop through a list of 10,000 series. Each series contains 4 elements. I want to grab the first element of each series and store it in an array.

```
count_datapoints_per_controller = []
for z in range(len(datapoints_per_controller)):
   var = datapoints_per_controller[z][z]
   count_datapoints_per_controller.append(var)
```

Comment: your second `[z]` should probably be `[0]` if you are after the first element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the code looks right except the [z][z], it should be [z][0] to get the first element.

`count_datapoints_per_controller = []
for z in range(len(datapoints_per_controller)):
   var = datapoints_per_controller[z][0]
   count_datapoints_per_controller.append(var)`

This should probably give you the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `list comprehension`

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
>>> [ d[0] for d in data]
[1, 5]
>>>
```

The problem in your code is, datapoints_per_controller[z][z], For selecting 1st element you should use the [0]. However you have used the [z] and it will throw index out of range exception.